# user defined size of a two dimensional array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, user-defined

I'm new to java, and i'm trying to make a array who's size is user defined. I'm staring off by filling in the entire array with zeros and moving from there. How should I go about doing that? What I have right now is something similar to: (input being my scanner object)

```
int num1, num2, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, active = 0;

num1 = input.nextInt();
num2 = input.nextInt();

int[][] ver = new int[num1][num2];

while(active == 0){

    ver [num3][num4] = 0;
    ++num4;

    if(num4 > num2){

        ++num3;
        num4 = 0;
    }

    if(num3 > num1){

        ++active

    }

}
```

This keeps giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0, making me think ver[0][0] doesn't exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of `num3` and `num4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking `num3` and `num4` properly (they both are allowed to reach the upper bound) so they will eventually go out of bounds.

Since you're just trying to fill your array with zeros why don't you consider the following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

int num1 = 2; // fixed number just for test purposes
int num2 = 2; // fixed number just for test purposes

int[][] ver = new int[num1][num2];
for (int[] row: ver)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);

System.out.println(ver[0][0]); // prints 0 as expected
```

Since every subarray (`row` in the example) is an array the above code will loop through them filling them with zeros, taking advantage of the `fill` method of the `Arrays` class, which you need to import as shown in the example.

Comment: i tried  

'for(int[] row: ver){
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
}
  
System.out.println(ver[0][0]);'

Comment: And what's the result? It should print `num1` times `num2` `0`s

Comment: it gives me an out of bounds exception on the print statement

Comment: that's weird. I just updated my answer with a MWE, which correctly prints 0 as expected. You may want to check you `num1` and `num2` values

Comment: variables num1 num2 and the array are declared outside an method, because they are edited from a deferent one than brought to another method to fill it with zeros. does this matter? num1 and num2 are static because otherwise it give me an error. I'm not sure what static actually does thought. I made a new class copied you code word by word and its works, so its me not you.

Comment: You should then post the missing part of your code that may affect the result, so that we can understand and help you out.

Comment: heres a link to the code with irrelevant methods hidden:
http://pastebin.com/d0C1uZn5

all methods shown:
http://pastebin.com/NAg5xp2E

Comment: Dont bother; i fixed it myself by giving the method where the zeros when handed out sizeX & Y as args, made a new array and made the zeros do to it, then made the origial array = the new one.

Thanks a lot for the Arrays.fill code. it saved me a lot of trouble. thanks for your time too, your where really helpful.

Comment: Ok I checked your code and you're initializing the array in the wrong place. Do `behind = new int [sizeX][sizeY];` at the end of your `start()` method and you will be ok.

Comment: Ok didn't see your last comment. If you initialize the array when declaring the variable, `sizeX` and `sizeY` wont't set yet, so you would be defining a 0x0 array. Moving the initialization after `sizeX` and `sizeY` are set fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no checking for the values of `num3` and `num4` in your code. Add proper restrictions as I envisage, you don't what them to be greater thatn `num1` and `num2` respectively.

If the value of num3 or num4 goes beyond the limit you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

This fails when `num4 == num2` as you are checking `num4 > num2`; because `num2` is the length of the array while index goes to `length-1`. Same goes with `num3` and `num1` comparison. Use `num2-1` and `num1-1` in the comparison as below:

```
    int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0,num4=0;
    num1 = input.nextInt();  //<--Input a value >0
    num2 = input.nextInt();  //<--Input a value >0
    int[][] ver = new int[num1][num2];
    int active = 0;
    while(active == 0){
        ver[num3][num4] = 0;
        ++num4;
        if(num4 > num2-1){     // or if(num4 >= num2)
            ++num3;
            num4 = 0;
        }
        if(num3 > num1-1){     // or if(num3 >= num1)
            ++active;
        }
    }
```

Comment: or simply use `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: In that case `=` will be sufficient but agree. `>=` will be also a good option.

Comment: Correct, even tough `>=` is a good defensive programming practice.